# HOWTO access request object in an invocation of a custom tag function in JSPs

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, httprequest, jsp-tags

In JSP pages I am using a custom JSTL function, which has the `request` object as one of the inputs.

Currently I am using the following way of accesing it in my JSP.

```
<c:if test="${custom:isVisitorFromNorthAmerica(request)}">
...
</c:if>
```

The tag function definition is as follows,

```
<function>
    <name>isVisitorFromNorthAmerica</name>
    <function-class>com.x.y.JspELFunctions</function-class>
    <function-signature>
        java.lang.Boolean isVisitorFromNorthAmerica(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
    </function-signature>
</function>
```

Inside the function definition of `custom#isVisitorFromNorthAmerica` the request object is null. I am not sure how to access the `request` object then, without resorting to scriptlets.

I made sure that the `request` object being sent to the custom tag is not null, because I added a scriptlet just before the custom function invocation & it is set properly.

Comment: Can you show your tag?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have updated the question with tag function definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. I need to access it using `pageContext`. So instead of calling it like so,

```
<c:if test="${custom:isVisitorFromNorthAmerica(request)}">
```

I need to call it like so,

```
<c:if test="${custom:isVisitorFromNorthAmerica(pageContext.request)}">
```